# Behat/Mink to submit form and check for confirmation text

Tags: php, behat, mink

I have my contact form getting submitted fine with Behat using 'And I press "Submit"', but sadly my 'Then I should see "Thank you for contacting us"' is failing.  I am assuming this is due to it running the test before the next page has loaded (meaning the text is not visible).  Is there a way to resolve this, or is this just not something that the tool was made to handle?

Thanks for any advice,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tweaking, it appears Goutte was getting upset, and so replaced it with PhantomJS.  This seems to have resolved the issue.

```
Behat\MinkExtension:
  base_url: http://local.yoopod.com
  selenium2: ~
  browser_name: phantomjs
```